# How to generate procedural/algorithmic vectors?

Tags: vector, patterns, procedural-art, generate-image-assets

I'm trying to find tools to achieve this kind of patterns and looks that seem procedural or algorithmic.

So far, the only way i think i could achieve this kind the results is tweaking with the blend tool of illustrator, or warping patterns.

Do you know any plugin or tool that outputs vectorial results?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lower one is easy the upper one is a bit trickyer, Its the gradient and intensity of pixels in a raster image. Oh and all yoyr really need is notepad

Comment: If someone is interested i found this software that is pretty close to what i needed in the first place at least for some applications.
 [Lost Minds' VectoRaster7](https://www.lostminds.com/vectoraster7/)